# Get coordinates from script tag, image tag, link

Tags: php, regex, geolocation, coordinates

I'm building a search engine for deals and I put all deals on a map, so I need coordinates from websites with scraping.

So, coordinates can be on scrit, tag, image, link, etc.

Is there any tool or any script, framework, that help me to quick get coordinates from some web sites ? How to do that? With PHP, XPath, regex, node, css selectors??? Some quick "getting coordinates" script.

Is there any solution for this, doing it manually is so hard because I need to do scraping on more that 10,000 web sites and on all sites coordinates is in script tag, or image or link ...

Any automated solution?

here is some cases:

```
 <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=44.796637,20.480168" target="_blank">prikaži na karti</a>

<iframe frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title=""  src="http://www.kolektiva.rs/beograd/dailydeal/vendor/map/center/44.815123,20.469887/"></iframe>

<iframe frameborder="0" height="230" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=el&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=207271638222613154872.00049df7bb569d7af0057&amp;ll=38.775499,23.483276&amp;spn=0.984971,1.257935&amp;z=8&amp;output=embed" width="230"></iframe>
```

you can add your cases, becouse on every site is different type of map...

so is there universal code for extracting coordinates not only from this examples - for every text???

Comment: So, what result do you want to get? This is a very undefined question and I can see the reasons someone has downvoted it.

Comment: there is 3 example so if i put this like string in $a variable how to write some regex for universal getting the coordinates

Comment: And what exactly would the `$a` string contain?

Comment: ok, look at my response, I edited it with a regex and a PHP example (considering that $s contains everything that is in your text sample). Now, I cannot try it so I suggest you to try that, and to write new more definite question if you face any new problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm I think you got a minus cause you seem to look for some kind of magics ... Or you are not clear and accurate enough maybe ...

Perhaps you should try to separate your problem into several isolated definite problems, because a sort of universal *geolocation coordinates web harvester* seems to be quite a very specific application ... Maybe it exists, I don't know, but ... sounds kind of magics for now :-)

So maybe try to make a clear, definite inventory of each case you may face to, and possibly begin to try to think about a possible extraction solution for each case ...

**That has been said**, first of all, are you sure an IP to GPS-coordinates won't be enough? If you have an URL for each of your deal, then it may be enough. In this case, you may want to have a look [at here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite), the free databases are updated each month but it should be accurate enough. They provide API for a [lot of dev environments](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api) and you can try their service freely [at this address](http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip?ips=www.google.com) (25 requests a day max)

Here is a quick [tutorial](http://www.phparch.com/2011/11/geolocation-its-easier-than-it-looks/) for working with the [geolitecity](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) database and [quova](http://developer.quova.com/) on PHP

I think PHP have a GeoIP module as well but I don't know if it's using the maxmind service, or another one, and I can't access the PHP website, it seems down for now. Try [this](http://www.google.ie/search?q=php%20geoip) later maybe,

**edit:** you need to say what kind of source you will have for your deals. Is it on big corporate website like ebay or amazon, or similar ? If yes, you may first want to check if they have proper API from which you may retrieve GPS coordinates for each deal easily ...

**edit#2:**
Ok, so from your samples, it seems that all your geolocation cases are with the form `23.987463,12.098374`, say <del>two</del> between one and three digits preceded with a 'minus' or not, followed with a dot, then 6 digits, then a comma, then <del>two</del> between one and three digits preceded with a 'minus' or not, followed with a dot and six digits again ... So, a regular expression for matching this format would be:

```
'-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6},-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6}'
```

Now, in PHP, you should do something like:

```
preg_match_all('-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6},-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6}',$s,$out);
```

where your input string is in `$s`, and where you get an array with your 3 GPS-coordinates in `$out`.

The array in $out will look something like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => 44.796637,20.480168
[1] => 44.815123,20.469887
[2] => 38.775499,23.483276
)
```

Now, I'm not a PHP guy, and I cannot try any code on my machine so I suggest you make some attempts, and if needed, ask new questions, more clear and definite, regarding the new problems you may meet ...

Comment: What I need is the solution that can extract coordinates from some string... etc, first I get code and do as a straing so $a is now text. How from $a to extract coordinates

Comment: I think with a regex you might be able to that quite easily. But I would need some samples on the things you want to that. Have you got some samples of text containing the coordinates you want to extract ? Maybe that definite question might worth a new answer, no ? Or reformulate your question maybe, add samples, etc.

Comment: ok,thanks,but what if some coordinates have a - (minus) before numbers ? :)

Comment: also coordinates in some cases have a 3 numbers etc. -122.345234

Comment: Ok so in this case, replace [0-9]{2} with -?[0-9]{1,3} ... Now your expression looks like '-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6},-?[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{6}'

Comment: The '?' means that the previous char maybe present or not ... The {1,3} means that the previous char (here, a class of char between 0 and 9) maybe repeated between 1 and 3 times

Answer (score 0):

(preg_match_all('#(([0-9-]+){1,3}.([0-9]+))#is', $string, $matches))

work!!!!

http://ideone.com/X5qNh

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule that coordinates have 6 decimals precision. I usually see between 4 and 10 but really it can be any number. The max is 180 though so maybe `'-?1?\d{1,2}\.\d{4,10}'`